# PHP stream_get_contents() behaves strangely reading an LOB from a database

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have 2 records in a table with similar CLOB data. Each of those are parsed from a query and then read into a string by php in a loop against the returned PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

it looks something like this after the query returns the results:

```
ID   |   NAME   |   DESCRIPTION   |   LOB_DEFINITION
4409     foo        blah blah         long text that is stored in a lob ~ 5k characters
4410     foobar     blah blah         some other long text stored in a lob ~ 5k characters
```

My problem is that once I start looping through this and reading contents from the LOBs they don't 'reset' So, any and all of the objects read will have the same values as the first LOB it read:

something like this:

```
foreach($result as $r) {
$lob = stream_get_contents($r['LOB_DEFINITION']);
echo $r['ID'].'-<i>'.$lob.'</i><HR>';
unset($lob);
}
```

results in output that looks like this:

4409-*long text that is stored in a lob ~ 5k characters*

---

4410-*long text that is stored in a lob ~ 5k characters*

**instead of what I would expect to get which would be:**

4409-*long text that is stored in a lob ~ 5k characters*

---

4410-*some other long text stored in a lob ~ 5k characters*

I've checked the Resource IDs as well and they are different resources...

I'm at a loss here... Does anyone have insight on this subject?

Comment: Why... are you using `stream_get_contents()` for this? I'm just wondering. Haven't you already pulled the result in? Why do you need `stream_get_contents()`. Is this something to do with using Oracle? Because as far as I can see from the manual, `stream_get_contents()` is more or less equivalent to `file_get_contents()`, except it operates on a stream... I fail to see how a retrieved resource from a DB is a stream in any way?

Comment: A retrieved LOB is a stream: if you simply echo $r['LOB_DEFINITION'] it will print to the screen a resource ID. this resource is a handle (similar to that of a file handle) that can and should be read through the stream_get_contents or something similar. It is and has been working for several other objects in my project, this is the first time I have worked looping through them however and it seems as though there's something funny going on with it.

Comment: Aha. Not familiar with Oracle / LOB. Hence the question. Might it be something about the stream not picking up/letting off after outputting the content? Maybe there's a reset/stop/setting for it? I see there are multiple examples and suggestions here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php - maybe you can find something which helps.

Answer (score 4):

Several hours of research resulted in the following:

returning a multi-record set from an oracle table where one of the columns is a clob datatype will result in the last record retrieved clob to be the value for ALL clobs retrieved. This is what was causing the behavior above.

What I ended up doing to solve the issue was first:

selecting all the records in which I planned to work with clobs (not the clobs themselves, just the record IDs)

I then loop through those record IDs and with separate database calls process the CLOB data 1 by 1 using the primary key to pull in the record to ensure no more than 1 record comes back with clob data. So in essence here is what is happening now:

after retrieving the ID from the table for all clobs I want to work with I parse through them thusly:

```
foreach($result as $r) {
  $query = 'select lob_definition from mytable where id = '.$r;
  $lobresult = oracleConnection->query($query)->fetchAll(FETCH_COLUM);
    $lob = stream_get_contents($lobresult);
    echo $r['ID'].'-<i>'.$lob.'</i><HR>';
    unset($lob);
}
```

something to that effect has solved my problem (all of it is abstracted in various methods, but essentially that's what is happening.

Comment: Thank you! I solved this problem following your suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Comment: It's never a good idea to DB-query inside loops but this is a working solution. The improvement proposed by @rouckas must be the accepted answer. This bug is still exist in PHP 8.1

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a long-standing bug in the PDO(OCI)::fetchAll
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46728

You don't have to make a separate query for each row as in Jeffs answer. You just have to avoid fetchAll. Based on the workaround suggested in the bug description, I'm using the following function to fetch all LOBs:

```
function fetchAllLOB(PDOStatement $stmt): array
{
    $result = [];
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
            if (is_resource($value)) {
                $row[$name] = stream_get_contents($value);
            }
        }
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved my day. I've been having this problem for almost two days. It's still pretty weird that it's been discovered since 2008 but it's still there without a fix.