# Read multiple CLOB data correctly - php / oracle

Tags: php, oracle, clob

In oracle DB, I have CLOB column in a table.
When I execute select command, to get all data this table, the result shows me only first CLOB registred in DB.
For example, I have a table caled News. This table has:

```
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|  New_Id (Number)    |  New_Title (Varchar2) |  New_Content (CLOB)    |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|          1          |       Title Test 1    |     Content test 1     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|          2          |       Title Test 2    |     Content test 2     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|          3          |       Title Test 3    |     Content test 3     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|          4          |       Title Test 4    |     Content test 4     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
```

In Oracle, I have a function that execute:

```
FOR linha IN (SELECT New_Id, New_Title, New_Content FROM New)
  LOOP
    outList := news_obj( line.New_Id, line.New_Title, line.New_Content);
    pipe row(outList );
  END LOOP;
```

I've tested this function, and works fine!

The PDO in php:

```
public function selectDB($sql,$params=null,$class=null)
{
    $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);

    if(isset($class)){
        $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,$class) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
    }else{
        $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
    }

    self::__destruct();
    return $rs;
}
```

Then set the object:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    $objNot = new news();
    $objNot->setNew_id($array[$i]->NEW_ID);
    $objNot->setNew_title($array[$i]->NEW_TITLE);
    $objNot->setNew_content(stream_get_contents($array[$i]->NEW_CONTENT));
    array_push($array2, $objNot);
}
return array2;
```

The result of query shows me the new_id and new_title correctly, but the new_content column is shows only the first data (Content test 1) for all.
The result shows this:

```
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|          1          |       Title Test 1    |     Content test 1     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|          2          |       Title Test 2    |     Content test 1     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|          3          |       Title Test 3    |     Content test 1     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
|          4          |       Title Test 4    |     Content test 1     |
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|
```

What is missing? Is there a wrong?

Comment: The problem was solved, following Jeff's suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387557/php-stream-get-contents-behaves-strangely-reading-an-lob-from-a-database

Comment: What's your PHP version? There was a locator reuse bug fixed in PHP 5.4.2 by https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57702  But overall, I still recommend using PHP OCI8 instead of PDO_OCI, since it doesn't have this kind of problem